# Why does the Points change its size when I use my post-processing effect?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, post-processing

In this video [LINK](https://jumpshoot.oleegarch.com/bytecoin4-background-stars.mp4) you can see that when i start my PostProcessing effect the background stars is changes its sizes

My explode effect (ShiningPass) can't influence to size of stars, fragment shader code below:

```c
void mainImage(const in vec4 inputColor, const in vec2 vUv, out vec4 outputColor) {
    vec2 uv = vUv.xy - vec2(0.5, 0.5);
    uv.x *= aspect;

    // get our distance and angle
    float dist = length(uv);
    float angle = atan(uv.y, uv.x) / PI;

    // rays
    float raysCount = 100.0;
    float noiseAngle = noise(vec2(uTime * SPEED, angle * raysCount)) * 0.2 + uProgress;
    float rays = noiseAngle - dist;
    float ray = smoothstep(0.0, SMOOTH_DIST, rays);

    // set final color
    vec4 color = inputColor;
    color.xyz += ray;
    outputColor = color;
}
```

How i generate background stars code:

```js
addBackgroundStars() {
    const scene = this.scene;
    const loader = new TextureLoader();
    const starsGeometry = new BufferGeometry();
    const starsCount = 5000;
    const starNear = 200;
    const starFar = 500;
    const vertices = randomSpherePoints(starsCount, [starNear, starFar]);

    starsGeometry.setAttribute('position', new Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));

    const starSprite = loader.load(require('@/assets/games/boom/background-star.png'));
    const starsMaterial = new PointsMaterial({
        'color': 0xFFFFFF,
        'size': 5,
        'map': starSprite,
        'blending': AdditiveBlending,
        'depthTest': false,
        'depthWrite': false
    });

    const stars = new Points(starsGeometry, starsMaterial);
    scene.add(stars);
}
```

In older version of three.js and postprocessing this bug was not, but when i moved the code to a new project with new versions i guess i missed something or something changed in modules...

in WebGLRenderer i added and deleted depth to true and false

i added and deleted depthTest true and false to PointsMaterial
i added and deleted depthWrite true and false to PointsMaterial